# Pythonic way of creating a recursive series of 1 and 0 based on a pandas time series level

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to clean up a code where I have a dataframe such has:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': {'2016-09-21': 13.30,
  '2016-09-22': 12.02,
  '2016-09-23': 12.28,
  '2016-09-26': 14.5,
  '2016-09-27': 13.1,
  '2016-09-28': 12.39,
  '2016-09-29': 14.02}})
```

I have a ON and OFF signal based on levels. when 'value' cross upward 14.39 I want to have 1 until it cross 12.50 downward such has:

```
df
             value  sig
2016-09-21 13.3000    0
2016-09-22 12.0200    0
2016-09-23 12.2800    0
2016-09-26 14.5000    1
2016-09-27 13.1000    1
2016-09-28 12.3900    0
2016-09-29 14.0200    0
```

I am approching the problem through a loop but I am pretty sure there's a better way to do it. here is my approach:

```
off, on, sig = 14.39, 12.50, 0
log = []
for level in df.itertuples():
    if level.value > off:
        sig = 1
    elif (sig == 1) & (level.value < on):
        sig = 0
    log.append([level.value, sig])
log = pd.DataFrame(log, index=df.index, columns=['value', 'sig'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution with `pandas.Series.where` method:

```
import numpy as np

ON, OFF = 14.39, 12.50
df['sig'] = 0                                 #  set the initial value to be 0
df['sig'] = (df.sig.where(df.value < ON, 1)   #  if value > ON, set it 1
                   .where((df.value < OFF) | (df.value > ON), np.nan)  
                                              #  if value < ON, and value > OFF, set it nan
                   .ffill().fillna(0))        # forward fill the nan value as they depend 
                                              # on their previous state, and fill initial 
                                              # value as 0
df

#           value   sig
#2016-09-21 13.30     0
#2016-09-22 12.02     0
#2016-09-23 12.28     0
#2016-09-26 14.50     1
#2016-09-27 13.10     1
#2016-09-28 12.39     0
#2016-09-29 14.02     0
```

A similar `np.where()` method with maybe clearer intention：

```
import numpy as np
df['sig'] = np.where(df.value > ON, 1, np.where(df.value < OFF, 0, np.nan))
df['sig'] = df.sig.ffill().fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom this looks good. I dont know why but for me the first and last index are equal to 1 but I was expecting 0s. `np.where(df.value > ON, 1, np.where(df.value < OFF, 0, np.nan))` yield  `array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.])`

Comment: Oups, ON and OFF was reverse in your example and I did not catch that. works perfectly many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['sig'] = (df['value'] < off & df['value'] > on).astype(int)
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: using `((df['value'] > on) & (df['value'] < off)).astype(int)` would not be recursive in nature, if you cross 13 and t-1 was 12.50, the signal need to wait for the next cross with 14.39 to start applying 1

Comment: sorry, didnt try it, maybe the construct `on < x < off`does not work in a vecorized manner.. Adapted the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Off top of my head and unverified.

```
v = df['value']
s = v.gt(14.39).sub(v.lt(12.5))
df['sig'] = s.where(s.ne(0). np.nan).ffill().add(1).div(2)
```